# AJAX / jQuery Usage for navigation tabs

Tags: php, ajax

I am wanting to implement AJAX into the admin pages of my Wordpress theme.  I seem to almost be there, but I am somehow fading-in the wrong class.

Please see this screenshot with the class labels provided:

[image: Theme Options Screenshot]

Here is what's happening:

1. I click on Appearance > Site Options and the page display correctly with a single page of options
2. I click on one of the top navigation tabs, and the page fades out correctly.
3. When the page fades back in - it appears like the 2nd screenshot below.

[image]

Here is the code that is currently handling the request:

```
 jQuery('.nav-tab').live('click', function(e){ 
     e.preventDefault();
     var link = jQuery(this).attr('href'); //Get the href attribute
 jQuery('.page-form').fadeOut(500, function(){ //fade out the content area
 jQuery("#loader").show(); // show the loader animation
    }).load(link + '.page-form', function(){ jQuery('.page-form').fadeIn(500, function(){ 
 jQuery("#loader").hide(); //hide the loader
   });
  });
 });
```

So I just need to know how to show only the "page form" class inside of the rendered content, not the entire wordpress admin area.

Comment: you load the whole page with the specified href. You need a server-side script that return only the requested content. But i don't know in wordpress has any built in solution or you need to write the ajax request handler.

Comment: Thanks for that - that is a good start to finding a solution

Comment: Putting a space before '.page-form' inside 'load()' may do the trick. See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're loading the entire page in your AJAX request (as mentioned by Bence) and modifying the response server-side *is* the best option, however, it *is* possible to fix this using jQuery;

```
jQuery('.nav-tab').on('click', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.page-form').load(jQuery(this).attr('href') + ' .page-form');
});
```

This should load the url from the location of the clicked link and extract the element with class '.page-form' from the result and replace the element selected by '.page-form' with its content. However;

- make sure that a [space] is present between the url and the selector (' .page-form'), a space is missing in your code
- using a 'class' as selector may return multiple elements, I'm not sure what the result will be in case multiple elements are selected

See the documentation here:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

NOTE:
You're using jQuery.live() in your code, which is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 (http://api.jquery.com/live/). You may want to rewrite your code and use jQuery.on() as its replacement (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Jeztah, yes I found this out myself as well in looking for an answer, which is great but now after fading there is no output.  I'm sure we are close here - not sure why this is off

Comment: Imho, the fading is the icing on the cake. Start with making the tabs 'work' (e.g. having them show the right content), then try to make them look 'nice' by adding the fade in/out effects. By trying to do it all at once, you're making it all overly complex to track what's going wrong

Comment: okay, I will do so.  Would you mind posting your code in a full example, I know it works, so I will mark your answer.  That would really help - I'm not good with jQuery so I do not understand how to strip down to bare-bones code.

Comment: I updated my example, haven't tested it will leave that to you :)

Comment: I found it - a silly mistake on my part.  I forgot to add the classes to the containers on each of those tab pages.  Thanks for the simple answer.

Comment: Hi Jeztah, my media upload button is not working now on the page after switching pages.....is there something else I might need to do in order to reset page so that this does not happen?  Either way thanks for your help.

Comment: If the media-upload button requires some javascript-initialization to start working, it's possible that that javascript is not triggered/loaded because you're only loading part of the html. It seems to me that the page has not been designed with 'ajax' loading in mind and requires additional modifications to have it work this way

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ajaxing in each individual tab, you could also just apply a [jQuery ui tabs widget](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) to the page. Then your markup would like something like this:

```
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-General">General Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-Layout">Layout Options</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-Content">Content Display</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-Advanced">Advanced Options</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-General">
    <!-- general settings form -->
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-Layout">
    <!-- Layout options form -->
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-Content">
    <!-- content display form -->
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-Advanced">
    <!-- advance options form -->
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This assumes you have the ability to add custom scripts to the head. You'll also have to take care to ensure that the tabs play nice with whatever save/cancel actions you provide, but that's the case for your AJAX solution as well. Just different.

**Edit:** I should have also linked to the [hide](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-hide) and [show](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-show) options, which control the fade in and fade out animations. I think you could add those options to the constructor (in addition to adding them after the `tabs()` call has finished, as in the example code in the linked documentation), like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs(
                hide : {
                    effect : 'fadeOut',
                    duration : 500
                },
                show : {
                    effect : 'fadeIn',
                    duration : 500
                }
            );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: that would definitely work, although the HTML display for Wordpress pages doesn't normally use `<li>` here, it messes up the display.  Not that I can't adjust with css, but I'd like to keep it simple. Maybe I'm limiting my options by thinking that way, not sure.

Comment: thanks Pat for that answer....I'm keep yours in mind as I check some more solutions on my side.

Comment: Hey, you're welcome. Keep it in mind if you can't get the ajax loading approach to work 100%.

Answer (score 1):

You could carry on passing the whole page using `AJAX` and then adding this over the navigation bar and header:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    return;
}
```

This checks to see if the page has been requested via `AJAX` and the `return;` will stop anything from loading there on.  Alternatively you can put code you want inside this `if` statement when it is being called via `AJAX`.